# preg_split using PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I was looking to split a string based on a regular expression but I also have interest in keeping the text we split on:

```
php > var_dump(preg_split("/(\^)/","category=Telecommunications &     CATV^ORcategory!=ORtest^caused_byISEMPTY^EQ"), null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
array(4) {
  [0]=> string(34) "category=Telecommunications & CATV"
  [1]=> string(18) "ORcategory!=ORtest"
  [2]=> string(16) "caused_byISEMPTY"
  [3]=> string(2) "EQ"
}
NULL
int(2)
```

What I do not understand is why am I not getting an array such as:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> "category=Telecommunications & CATV"
  [1]=> "^"
  [2]=> "ORcategory!=ORtest"
  [3]=> "^"
  [4]=> "caused_byISEMPTY"
  [5]=> "^"
  [6]=> "EQ"
}
```

Additionally, how could I change my regular expression to match "^OR" and also "^".  I was having trouble with a lookbehind assertion such as:

```
$regexp = "/(?<=\^)OR|\^/";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work as expected:

```
var_dump(preg_split('/(\^)/','category=Telecommunications &     CATV^ORcategory!=ORtest^caused_byISEMPTY^EQ', -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE));
```

the closing bracket of preg_split() is at the wrong place.

additional question:

```
/(\^OR|\^)/
```

Comment: Just to be clear, it's the ) that's in the wrong place. Because of that, the PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE wasn't being submitted as part of the function call.

Comment: My apologies, I think this is a fine indication it is time to stop coding for the day.  Sorry for wasting time.